# What is the best way to model document similarity between different string parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, modeling, sentence-similarity, nlp-question-answering

I have a problem of predicting solutions to problems faced by users.

The problem setting is like this:

We have a database of problems and solutions. For each problem we have three parameters to represent it.

1. **JobName** (String - Name of the Job)
2. **JobId** (Integer - Id of the Job)
3. **RootCause** (String - Cause of that problem).

Each problem has a corresponding solution added by that user who faced that problem. That solutions parameter is

1. **Solution** (String - Solution entered by user for that problem)

So we wanted to make use of that database and predict the solutions for new problems (a problem is a set of jobname, jobid, rootcause - all are strings)

We initially came up with this solution.
*We just want to identify problems(set of jobname, jobid, rootcause) similar to our query problem and give the solution to the closest problem.*
But in this case we don't have any way to measure the training error like we have in the house price prediction problems.

In general, how to we approach this problem, and what kind of machine learning models do we need to use ?

Comment: I would suggest you to identify the features first. JobID wouldn't make any sense. So, If jobName and rootcause would help you predict the solutions. you should train your model with them to predict solution

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you want to build kind of the recommendation system. According to the cause of the problem, suggest list of the recommended solutions. One of the possible solution - use [word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) for vectorisation `RootCause` and then try to find similar problems using, vectors similarity.

Comment: Assuming we do one hot encoding for `jobid` field and use vectorization for `rootCause` as you said, how do we assign the weights to both the jobid and the rootCause ?. For this we need to measure the training error of our model. I just need some help in modelling the problem for measuring the training error.

Comment: For be able to measure the training error, you should know "right" answers. But you need to find "closest" problems. When you have vector representation for the all RootCauses, you can find similar to the new problem, using similarity measures, for instance, cosine similarity between two vectors.

Comment: So how do I assign weights to jobid and rootCause when finding similar problems ?

Comment: Instead of the weight, you could use cosine distance. If two vectors (RootCauses) have cosine distance near 1 - this is similar "problems", if near 0 - quite different (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html). So you can show to the user 10 the most closest problems.

Comment: The distance between rootCauses is fine but who do you incorporate the jobName parameter ? What weights do you assign for the 1. Distance between rootCauses and 2. Distance between jobids ?